# How to fix 'There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. '?

Tags: javafx

I downloaded JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0, then I made a new JavaFX Project in Eclipse.

Unfortunately, this error occurs:

> The import Javafx cannot be resolved

Below the log:

```
Eclipse version : 2019-09
JDK version : 13

Problem Description

Application cannot be resolved to a type
BorderPane cannot be resolved to a type
BorderPane cannot be resolved to a type
Scene cannot be resolved to a type
Scene cannot be resolved to a type
Stage cannot be resolved to a type
The import javafx cannot be resolved
The import javafx cannot be resolved
The import javafx cannot be resolved
The import javafx cannot be resolved
The method launch(String[]) is undefined for the type Main

Warnings
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-12. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.  hello       Build path  JRE System Library Problem

Console
Error: Unable to initialize main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage
```

I've already downloaded e(fx)clipse 3.6.0

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try{

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed code and error blocks

Comment: JavaFX is not included with JDK 13 and e(fx)clipse does not include JavaFX either. Do you have the JavaFX JAR files?

Comment: thank you for your support. now i can use javafx